# Issue on appending a file in android

Tags: android

I am creating an android application which reads and writes data to a file in the location `/sdcard/ReadandWrite/`.when i writing to that file it does not write in append mode.it will removes the old data and writes the new one.please help me to solve this.Here is my code.

```
private File openfile() {
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/ReadandWrite");
    dir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(dir, "myfile.txt");
    file.setWritable(true);
    if(file.exists())
    {
        file.canRead();
        file.setWritable(true);

    }
    else {
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return file;
}

private void writetofile() {


    try {
        File file=openfile();
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter =
                new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file));
        myOutWriter.append(text.getText());

        myOutWriter.close();
        myOutWriter.close();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "Done writing SD 'mysdfile.txt'",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Start with complete removal of `openfile()` function as it serves nothing. You forgot to tell what it does now instead of appending.

Comment: @greenapps it will removes the old data and writes the new one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure the FileOutputStream to use `append` mode. From [JDK documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29):

> public FileOutputStream(String name,
>                   boolean append)
>                    throws FileNotFoundException
>
> Creates a file output stream to write to the file with the specified
>   name. If the second argument is true, then bytes will be written to
>   the end of the file rather than the beginning. A new FileDescriptor
>   object is created to represent this file connection.
>
> First, if there is a security manager, its checkWrite method is called
>   with name as its argument.
>
> If the file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does
>   not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other
>   reason then a FileNotFoundException is thrown.
>
> Parameters:
>       name - the system-dependent file name
>       append - if true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning Throws:
>       FileNotFoundException - if the file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or
>   cannot be opened for any other reason.
>       SecurityException - if a security manager exists and its checkWrite method denies write access to the file. Since:
>       JDK1.1 See Also:
>       SecurityManager.checkWrite(java.lang.String)

So change 
`OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file));`

to

`OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file, true));`